# Append Scapy Results in Dictionary Format Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, scapy

I wrote my script using python and it worked successfully. I obtained, identified and printed `addr1,` `addr2,` and `addr3` in my terminal. However, I ran into several errors while attempting to appending those results to a CSV file in a dictionary format.

This is my script previously when I got my results printed in terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import *
import os

devices = set()
interface = "wlan0mon"
iface = "wlan0mon"

def sniffmgmnt(p):
    if p.haslayer(Dot11):
            devices.add(p.addr1)
            devices.add(p.addr2)
            devices.add(p.addr3)
            print(devices)

while True:
    for channel in range(1, 14):
            os.system("iwconfig" + iface + "channel" + str(channel))
            sniff(iface=interface, prn=sniffmgmnt, count=3, timeout=3, store=0)
```

I then attempted to append those results to a CSV file in a dictionary format where `addr3` is the **key**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import *
from snifferCSV import CSV
import os
aps = dict()
devices = set()

headers = ['addr3', 'addr2', 'addr1']
csvFile = CSV('data.csv', headers)

interface = "wlan0mon"
iface = "wlan0mon"

def sniffmgmnt(p):
    if p.haslayer(Dot11):
            source.append(p.addr1);
            receiving.append(p.addr2);
            destination.append(p.addr3);
            csvFile.addToCSV( [addr3, addr2, addr1] )
while True:
    for channel in range(1, 14):
            os.system("iwconfig" + iface + "channel" + str(channel))
            sniff(iface=interface, prn=sniffmgmnt, count=3, timeout=3, store=0)
```

However the script only outputs the headers in terminal, and my CSV file remains empty.

Below I have included my CSV class **snifferCSV.py**:

```
      class CSV(object):
        csvFile = None
        fileName = data.csv
        def __init__(self,fileName,headers):
            self.fileName = fileName
            self.prepareCSVFile(headers)
    def prepareCSVFile(self,headers):
            self.csvFile = open(self.fileName, 'w')
            headerString = self.prepareValues(headers)
            self.writeToCSV(headerString)
    def prepareValues(self,valueList):
            line = str()
            for item in valueList[:-1]:
                    line = line + str(item) + ','
            line += valueList[-1]
            return line
    def addToCSV(self,valueList):
            valueLine = self.prepareValues(valueList)
            self.writeToCSV(valueLine)
    def writeToCSV(self,line):
            print(line)
            self.csvFile.write(line)
```

My goal is to append my results in dictionary format to a CSV file where `addr3` is the key. However, my logic about this process is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance
-JJ

Comment: try to change `open(self.fileName, 'w')` --> `open(self.fileName, 'a')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @coder advice and changed 
`open(self.fileName, 'w')` to `open(self.fileName, 'a')` however only my headers were appended to the csv file.

I ended up scratching my `snifferCSV.py` class and instead embedded the dictionary function within my main file where I used the pairwise dict constructor and zip function to append my data to the csv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from scapy.all import *
import csv
import os

interface = "wlan0mon"
iface = "wlan0mon"

def sniffmgmnt(p):
    if p.haslayer(Dot11):
            keys = [(p.addr3)]
            values = [(p.addr1, p.addr2)]
            my_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
            with open('data.csv','a') as f:
                    w = csv.writer(f)
                    w.writerows(my_dict.items())
 while True:
    for channel in range(1, 14):
            os.system("iwconfig " + iface + " channel " + str(channel))
            sniff(iface=interface, prn=sniffmgmnt)
```